# How to Combine two non equal arrays by key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two associative arrays one has length of 4 and 2nd has length of 3.
e.g

Array 1:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[walker] => 5295
[districts] =>
[main_city] => Riyadh
[sub_city] => Riyadh
[ofd] => 42
[delivered] => 0
[undelivered] => 0
[returned] => 0
[successRate] => 0
)

[1] => Array
(
[walker] => 5293
[districts] => Al Malaz, Al Murabaa, As Sinaiyah, Al Wisham, Al Amal, Ad Dubiyah, Utaiqah, Al Jaradiyah, Manfuhah
Aljadidah, Ad Dirah, No District, Ghubairah, Umm Salim, Al Wazarat, Jarir, Riyadh, Manfuhah, Riyadh Air Base
[main_city] => Riyadh
[sub_city] => Riyadh
[ofd] => 32
[delivered] => 0
[undelivered] => 0
[returned] => 0
[successRate] => 0
)

[2] => Array
(
[walker] => 5290
[districts] => Al Qabil, Al Hadn, Al Faisaliyah, Al-Athaybah, Al Araysah Aljanubi Subdivision, Al Fahd, Al Araysah Ash
Shamali Subdivision
[main_city] => Najran
[sub_city] => Najran
[ofd] => 48
[delivered] => 0
[undelivered] => 0
[returned] => 0
[successRate] => 0
)

[3] => Array
(
[walker] => 5289
[districts] => Al Jamiah, An Nazlah Al Yamaniyah, An Nazlah Ash Sharqiyah, Madain Al Fahd, Al Aziziyah, Abhur
Aljanubiah, Abrug Ar Rughamah
[main_city] => Jeddah
[sub_city] => Jeddah
[ofd] => 43
[delivered] => 0
[undelivered] => 0
[returned] => 0
[successRate] => 0
)
```

)

Array 2:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[walker] => 5295
[districts] =>
[main_city] => Riyadh
[sub_city] => Riyadh
[ofd] => 42
[delivered] => 0
[undelivered] => 0
[returned] => 0
[successRate] => 0
)

[1] => Array
(
[walker] => 5293
[districts] => Al Malaz, Al Murabaa, As Sinaiyah, Al Wisham, Al Amal, Ad Dubiyah, Utaiqah, Al Jaradiyah, Manfuhah
Aljadidah, Ad Dirah, No District, Ghubairah, Umm Salim, Al Wazarat, Jarir, Riyadh, Manfuhah, Riyadh Air Base
[main_city] => Riyadh
[sub_city] => Riyadh
[ofd] => 32
[delivered] => 0
[undelivered] => 0
[returned] => 0
[successRate] => 0
)
)
```

i want to combine both arrays by key so i can get 0,1,2,3.  index 0 and 1 are matched but i want to get index 2 and 3 as well from Array1.

I have tried `array_key_exists($key, $Array1)` in for each loop. but its not working. can you please provide me hints what i am doing wrong here. or name any php function that can do this quickly.

Thanks

Comment: `array_key_exists($key, $Array2)` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes if key of Array 1 exist in Array 2 or not. but in this else part is not working

Comment: Show the code then!

Comment: Do you always want to replace the values of array1 with the existing values in array2? In that case you could just loop through array2 and copy each value to array1, right?

Comment: @DirkScholten one of they key like ofd will be only in array 2. so i need all values from array 1 and array 2...

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just need array [union](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)?

```php
$array2 + $array1;
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, until you post you current code. Don't go inside foreach loop of array 1 :)